# Wordpress ACF if statement

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've used Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Checkbox option. One option is 'red', second 'blue'. I want to create a condition for checking what color was selected by the user.
This is my code:

```js
 <?php 
 $val = get_field( 'checkbox' );
   if ( $val=='red' ) {
    echo ' value is red';
    } else {
    echo 'value is not red';
    }
 ?>
```

This code should output 'value is red' if the user checked the red option, but it doesn' work. Who knows what could be the problem? Bellow are attached the assets.[image][image]

Comment: `This code should output 'value is red' if the user checked the red option` Checked the option where? The code you posted will only work if you're checking the red option in the backend.

Comment: maybe you can do `echo $val` and check its value

Comment: @APAD1, the red option is checked in the backend, but code doesn't work

Comment: @aleberguer, i don't want to  echo the value, for me is important to display especially the  ' value is red'.

Comment: Then do as @aleberguer suggested and echo out `$val` to see what, if any, result you're getting. Would help if you posted a screenshot of the ACF configuration as well.

Comment: @APAD1, i added screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

With your current configuration, ACF is going to [return an array](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/) which is why it's not currently working. You will need to [check to see if `red` is in the array](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead:

```
<?php
    $val = get_field( 'checkbox' );
    if (in_array('red', $val)) {
        echo ' value is red';
    } else {
        echo 'value is not red';
    }
?>
```

That being said, if this is your actual use-case, I would suggest a [true/false field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/) instead. With the current configuration, a user could select `blue` as well as `red` and it would still return `value is red` on the frontend.